# Android - Trying to set an alarm on the first Monday of each month

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create an alarm on the first Monday of each month.  Here is my code:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FilterOrderBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
if(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis() > 0 ) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Today is the 12th of June.  This code creates an alarm trigger that is 1382399999 millis away or 15.9 days.  That will only take me to the end of the 27th.  I have thought about doing it with Joda, but there are issues with the Joda library with Android.  It is really slow.  Can anyone show me how to do this with the native Android libraries?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you doing this subtraction: `calendar.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: To see if the day is already past, but I should be evaluating if it is positive not negative.  Still only gives me 15.9 days.  Thanks for pointing it out though. I will edit.